# Как добавить несколько маркеров на карту? И сделать ссылки на маркеры в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда необходимо вставить вторую переменную в гугл скрипт:

```css
#map {
 margin: 0 auto
 width: 380px
 height: 340px
  }
```

```html
<button>
<a class="btn-map-link" href="#">Адрес 1 на карте</a>
</button>
<button>
<a class="btn-map-link" href="#">Адрес 1 на карте</a>
</button>
<div id="map"></div>




<script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHgYvdyI9XACsCvGjTWTv7k1keZYNEpEM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

И где взять ссылку чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на карте отображался нужный маркер?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, Теперь не понятно куда девается первый маркер, а так все работает:
[Ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/783383/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-google-map-%D0%A3%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE)